# F6 shortcut for NppExec not working anymore in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, nppexec

I can't seem to get F6 to work anymore to pull up the Execute in Notepad++'s NPPExec function. It was working fine until two days ago. None of the other function keys work to pull up Execute either.

Any ideas what happened?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have installed a new plugin which uses the same shortcut. The collisions are poorly handled in N++. Go to `settings->shortcut mapper->plugin` commands to fix this.

Comment: Worked. It was spellchecker addin causing the collision. Thanks much.

Comment: Shortcut collisions are *still* on the N++ bug fix list as of Aug 2012: Shortcut mapper can collide - ID: 3486336  [http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3486336&group_id=95717&atid=612382]